# What is wrong with this small for/if loop logic?

Tags: java

This code is asking for how many numbers the user will input and then it takes each of those. In the end it should return the smallest value. I know about Math.min methods, I'm just struggling with why the logic below doesn't work, it always prints the last input instead the smallest one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch5_smallestValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input how many numbers and then input each one");
        int hMany = sc.nextInt();

        int firstNum = sc.nextInt();
        int smallest = firstNum;

        for (int i = hMany; i > 1; i--){

           int input = sc.nextInt();
           if (smallest < input){
               smallest = input;
            } 

         }

        System.out.println("smallest = " + smallest);

    }

}
```

Comment: shouldn't the condition be `smallest > input`? Run through the code manually and you will be able to find such mistakes yourself.

Comment: its because your condition in the `if` is wrong. Check the above comment

Comment: Ok, many thanks for that! Its confusing though as in my head smallest value should be smaller ie " < " and not larger (>) than other input numebrs :) EDIT: I get it now :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Change (smallest < input) to **(smallest > input).**